# RuntimeError: RuntimeError: super-class __init__() was never called, хотя он был вызван

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, отладка

[**GitHub с кодом**](https://github.com/StarterCraft/Hyrex_AsQamm)

Cуществует приложение на Python и PyQt5. Имеется некоторый класс пользователя `User`, наследуемый от класса системы пользователей `AqUserSystem`. При запуске приложения файлы стандартных и системных пользователей загружаются из JSON, затем на основании полученных данных создаются экземпляры класса пользователя. Проблема заключается в том, что система успешно загружает стандартных пользователей `~!guest!~` u `~!dev!~`, но как только дело доходит до создания экземпляра класса пользователя из файла, находящегося в `data/personal/`, то метод не может создать экземпляр класса, потому что не видит экземпляра `AqUserSystem`, хотя до этого при создании экземпляров из `data/system/` всё было прекрасно. Для вызова ошибки понадобится [файл](https://pastebin.com/RybF8p63) кастомного пользователя, поместить который нужно в `data/personal/`.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQammDekstopConrol\AsQammDekstop.py", line 91, in <module>
    usersCore.loadUsers(usersCore, root)
  File "G:\Work\Code\Hyrex AsQamm\AsQammDekstopConrol\_asQamm\asQammUsers.py", line 181, in loadUsers
    instance = User(core, root, (jsonString['id']), (jsonString['description']), (jsonString['type']), str(self.item),  
RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type AqUsersSystem was never called
```

Comment: а что с предыдущим вопросом?

Comment: он уже завершён

Comment: отлично, теперь вижу что завершен. Скажите пожалуйста вы можете составить минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который бы сосредоточился только на указанной вами проблеме? И что это за файл, который вы предлагаете скачать, для получения ошибки?

Comment: __init__.py  0 байт.....попробуйте его удалить/переименовать  """2 слеша инит 2 слеша""" а не жирный инит )

Comment: @S.Nick, 1) мой код слишком комплексный. Каждый компонент напрямую зависит друг от друга. Если я попытаюсь написать МВП, то это займёт слишком много времени, и, кроме того, в результате создания МВП получится тот же самый код, который я попытаюсь сократить. 2) Это файл является зашифрованной строкой, представляющей из себя JSON-словарь. На основе таких фалов генерируются экземпляры класса пользователя.В целях безопасности все файлы данных пользователей зашифрованы. Они расшифровываются во время выполнения метода `loadUsers`.

Comment: @S.Nick, Суть моей просьбы заключается в том, чтобы Вы запустили моё приложение, скачав его с GitHub и поняли бы, в чём проблема. Кроме того, если вы сделаете так, Вам будет гораздо легче понять, в каком месте и при каких обстоятельствах происходит ошибка, чем если я буду словами вам объяснять тут.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке 181 файла `asQammUsers.py` все го лишь нужно заменить `str(self.item)` на `str(item)`. Простая невнимательность!

Answer (score 2):

> `RuntimeError: super-class __init__() of type AqUsersSystem was never called`

В конструкторы классов добавьте вызов родительского конструктора. Для виджетов `Qt` это обязательно

У вас я вижу, что нужно вызывать для этих классов:

- [class AqUsersSystem(AqMainWindow):](https://github.com/StarterCraft/Hyrex_AsQamm/blob/8e3935404336e34a67b83da1a9e005d052c5ea88/AsQammDekstopConrol/_asQamm/asQammUsers.py#L11)
- [class User(AqUsersSystem):](https://github.com/StarterCraft/Hyrex_AsQamm/blob/8e3935404336e34a67b83da1a9e005d052c5ea88/AsQammDekstopConrol/_asQamm/asQammUsers.py#L416)

Выглядит это так:

```
super().__init__()
```

Например:

```
class AqUsersSystem(AqMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, root):
       super().__init__()
```

---

**PS.**

Можно вызывать родительский конструктор указывая класс родителя напрямую, но мне кажется через `super()` лучше (тут видно, что наследуем от `QMainWindow` и от него же вызываем конструктор):

```
class AqMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
```